# Read more popup that displays the entire content - HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I'm designing a few static HTML pages and one such page is about the team members and their description. Each description is about three paragraphs. I need only to show the first 200 chars initially appended with a readmore link. When the user clicks it, I want the rest of the content to open up in a popup or append in the viewport itself... I couldn't figure out a way to do it. Can you please show me a method to do it. Is it possible to do it with css? Or should I use jQuery? If either... Please show me a demo.

Here is a fiddle to explain:

This is the paragraph:

`<div id = "paragraph">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque varius dictum nibh, in fringilla felis ornare et. Cras at rutrum libero. Morbi dignissim magna et condimentum laoreet. Sed sodales pretium quam vitae bibendum. Aenean congue urna in luctus facilisis. Maecenas molestie pretium orci in iaculis. Sed cursus elit at euismod tristique. Vestibulum vitae mauris ut ante cursus ornare non quis nibh. Quisque dictum lacus est, vitae tincidunt dui dapibus eu. Curabitur a convallis lectus. Donec ac tincidunt risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; </p> </div>`

I need to show the users only upto : `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque varius dictum nibh, in fringilla felis ornare et. Cras at rutrum libero.` and then a `read more` link followed.

When the user clicks on the link, I need to see a popup or show the remaining content of the div. I'm not so much of a web developer. Please help me to figure out a way. If it's Jquery or javascript show me a demo with is JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N9HUA/

Comment: you need some js to do this...

Comment: I don't think he should be downvoted just because he isn't sure which technology or technique to use... Anyway: Reading the beginners' articles here might help you, if you're not comfortable with JS/jQuery (yet): http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Thanks for the wiki link @sb. I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of these options:

1. If you want more customization: [jQuery UI Show Efect](http://jqueryui.com/show/)
2. If you want it all organized: [jQuery UI Accordion Widget](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)